# VBA SerialPort_DataReceived Delay or not all data is received

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

G'day.

Having some problems with Serial through VBA, basic program. Sends char to Arduino, Arduino receives char, accesses SD card and prints to Serial. WinForm collects this data as a variable and writes to .csv file.

Sending char (yes I know tis string atm planning on changing :) )

```
    Private Sub Button_Download_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Download.Click
        Dim downloadChar As String = "a" & vbCrLf
        SerialPort1.Write(downloadChar)
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = devName
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

Receiving Bytes

```
   Private Sub Serialport1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        MsgBox("Fired")
        Dim strBuilder As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For index = 1 To SerialPort1.BytesToRead
            strBuilder.Append(Convert.ChangeType(SerialPort1.ReadByte(), GetType(Char)))
        Next
        Dim myString = strBuilder.ToString()
        TextBox2.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + myString
        Dim Path As String
        Path = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, myString)
    End Sub
```

Problem is the _datareceived sub is fired more then once (twice currently 2kb filesize), which writes over the myString.

If I add a message box such as "Fired" and wait a bit before clicking "ok" it works perfectly as seen below. That is fine for my use but for larger file size the waiting time would be unknown.

I have tried do loops, adding variables to bytestoread such as startBytes & moreBytes & checking in that loop if moreBytes > 0 exit do. Tried variables/dialogs other than MsgBox/timers.

Question: Any other way to delay _datarecieved so that all bytes are able to be received before reading bytestoreceive?

Apologies for noob question. :(

Comment: You say "VBA" once in the title and once in the question but you've tagged the question VB.NET and the code is certainly VB.NET. Does this question actually have anything to do with VBA?

Comment: You don't need to delay anything. Just don't try to use the data before you have read all of it. If the event is raised twice then store the data that is read the first time and then append to it the second time, then use it.

Comment: Also, don't set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `False`. That is a terrible idea and completely unnecessary because you can just learn how to marshal a call to the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I only started this yesterday and am very inexperienced so your comments are much appreciated especially regarding syntax. I have moved the code to another sub. The idea was to click the download button -> select the file path -> collect the data. I assume the next step is to determine when there are no more bytes to receive, then to trigger the save file. Cheers :)